# STM32 gets stuck in While loop

Tags: stm32, embedded, arm

I am new enough with STM32 programming. But now I am working with a environmental parameter monitoring module based on STM32F401RE development board. Now I am facing a strange problem. When I try to display data from DHT11 module to OLED screen (ssd1306), the data is visible on the screen but does not update at all. When I press the reset button on the board, then the data is updated and I can see the changes. Maybe someone was facing a similar problem? Maybe I'm facing with a badly configured clock? I add my code:

main.c

```
 /* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "fonts.h"
#include "ssd1306.h"
#include "dwt_stm32_delay.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

uint8_t Rh_byte1, Rh_byte2, Temp_byte1, Temp_byte2;
uint16_t sum, RH, TEMP;
int temp_low, temp_high, rh_low, rh_high;
char temp_char1[2], temp_char2, rh_char1[2], rh_char2;
uint8_t check = 0;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
void set_gpio_output (void)
{
    /*Configure GPIO pin output: PA2 */
  //GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void set_gpio_input (void)
{
    /*Configure GPIO pin input: PA2 */
// GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void DHT11_start (void)
{
    set_gpio_output ();  // set the pin as output
//  HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, 0);   // pull the pin low
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, 0);   // pull the pin low
    DWT_Delay_us (18000);   // wait for 18ms
    set_gpio_input ();   // set as input
}

void check_response (void)
{
    DWT_Delay_us (40);
    //if (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1)))
    if (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)))
    {
        DWT_Delay_us (80);
        //if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1))) check = 1;
        if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4))) check = 1;
    }
    //while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1)));   // wait for the pin to go low
    while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));   // wait for the pin to go low
}

uint8_t read_data (void)
{
    uint8_t i,j;
    for (j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        //while (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1)));   // wait for the pin to go high
        while (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));   // wait for the pin to go high
        DWT_Delay_us (40);   // wait for 40 us
        //if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1)) == 0)   // if the pin is low
        if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)) == 0)   // if the pin is low
        {
            i&= ~(1<<(7-j));   // write 0
        }
        else i|= (1<<(7-j));  // if the pin is high, write 1
        //while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1)));  // wait for the pin to go low
        while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));  // wait for the pin to go low
    }
    return i;
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  DWT_Delay_Init();
  SSD1306_Init();  // initialise
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    DHT11_start ();
    check_response ();
    Rh_byte1 = read_data ();
    Rh_byte2 = read_data ();
    Temp_byte1 = read_data ();
    Temp_byte2 = read_data ();
    sum = read_data();
    if (sum == (Rh_byte1+Rh_byte2+Temp_byte1+Temp_byte2))    // if the data is correct
    {

        SSD1306_GotoXY (0,0);
        SSD1306_Puts("TEMP:- ",&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Temp_byte1/10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Temp_byte1%10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Puts("C",&Font_11x18, 1);
        //display
        SSD1306_GotoXY (0,30);
        SSD1306_Puts("RH:- ",&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Rh_byte1/10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Rh_byte1%10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Puts("%",&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_UpdateScreen();
        //HAL_Delay (1000);
        }
    }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 400000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Clock config

[image]

Comment: You should use some kind of debugger. If you don't have a hardware for that then employ some other debugging techniques, such as GPIO output connected to LEDs or testpoints accessible with a scope probe. Or even some serial port output. We definitely can't debug the whole design for you.

Comment: If the received checksum is a byte, the sum of four previous bytes can be larger than the checksum and they might not match. What if you simply update the screen every time, and even include a counter that advances by one each loop to see where it gets stuck or does it run. Also, which board is it? If it has a debugger, you should already be debugging it.

Comment: @remark Which while loop? there are several

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I can't say that I did a very big job, but I tried to launch all the DHT functions one after the other, and see if the main loop gets stuck. The code did not crash at any point.

Then I slightly changed the functions of DHT sensor, and then the whole sequence of DHT code was like this:

```
uint8_t Rh_byte1, Rh_byte2, Temp_byte1, Temp_byte2;
uint16_t sum, RH, TEMP;
int temp_low, temp_high, rh_low, rh_high;
char temp_char1[2], temp_char2, rh_char1[2], rh_char2;
uint8_t check = 0;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;



    void set_gpio_output (void)
{
    /*Configure GPIO pin output: PA2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}



void set_gpio_input (void)
{
    /*Configure GPIO pin input: PA2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}



void DHT11_start (void)
{
    DWT_Delay_Init();
    set_gpio_output ();  // set the pin as output
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, 0);   // pull the pin low
    DWT_Delay_us (18000);   // wait for 18ms
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, 1);   // pull the pin high
    DWT_Delay_us (20);   // wait for 20us
    set_gpio_input ();   // set as input
}



void check_response (void)
{
    DWT_Delay_us (40);
    if (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)))
    {
        DWT_Delay_us (80);
        if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4))) check = 1;
        else check = -1;
    }
    while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));   // wait for the pin to go low
    //if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));   // wait for the pin to go low
    //return check;
}



uint8_t read_data (void)
{
    uint8_t i,j;
    for (j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        while (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));   // wait for the pin to go high
        //if (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));   // wait for the pin to go high
        DWT_Delay_us (40);   // wait for 40 us
        if (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)))   // if the pin is low
        {
            i&= ~(1<<(7-j));   // write 0
        }
        else i|= (1<<(7-j));  // if the pin is high, write 1
        while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));  // wait for the pin to go low
        //if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4)));  // wait for the pin to go low
    }
    return i;
}
```

In my main while loop I added LED blinking routine and also I started sending test messages to the terminal:

```
while (1)
  {

        DHT11_start ();
        check_response ();
        Rh_byte1 = read_data ();
        Rh_byte2 = read_data ();
        Temp_byte1 = read_data ();
        Temp_byte2 = read_data ();
        sum = read_data();

if (sum == (Rh_byte1+Rh_byte2+Temp_byte1+Temp_byte2))    // if the data is correct
    {
        SSD1306_GotoXY (0,0);
        SSD1306_Puts("TEMP:- ",&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Temp_byte1/10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Temp_byte1%10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Puts("C",&Font_11x18, 1);
        //display
        SSD1306_GotoXY (0,30);
        SSD1306_Puts("RH:- ",&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Rh_byte1/10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Putc((Rh_byte1%10)+48,&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_Puts("%",&Font_11x18, 1);
        SSD1306_UpdateScreen();
        HAL_Delay (1000);
        //NVIC_SystemReset(); //worst case scenario

        // Green on-board LED
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay (1000);
        //DWT_Delay_us (40);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "1", 10, 100);
        HAL_Delay (1000);

     }
  }
```

So far, after connecting the power supply and restarting the board, the program is running smoothly without much interruption.